# Improved error estimate for Conjugate Gradient Method

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be SPD. The error estimate for the conjugate gradient method is given by 
\begin{equation}
 \|x_* - x_m \|_A \leq 2 \left( \frac{\sqrt{\kappa}-1}{\sqrt{\kappa}+1} \right)^m \| x_* - x_0 \|_A
\end{equation}
where $x_*$ is the exact solution, $x_j$ are the approximate solutions of $Ax=b$, and
\begin{equation}
 \kappa = \frac{\lambda_{max}(A)}{\lambda_{min}(A)}.
\end{equation}
Assume that the eigenvalues of $A$ satisfy $0 < \lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2 \leq \, ... \, \leq \lambda_{n-1} << \lambda_n$. I would like to find an improved error estimate for this assumption. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the ideas in [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0045-7825(76)90056-6) and [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/imamat/20.1.61). Maybe you may find some pointers and/or theorems also in [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=hNpJg_pUsOwC) book (in the section on the convergence rate of CG).

Let $\Pi_k$ denotes a set of polynomials $p$ of the degree at most $k$ such that $p(0)=1$. The development of the classical CG convergence bound starts with the bound
$$
\frac{\|e_k\|_A}{\|e_0\|_A}\leq\min_{p\in\Pi_k}\max_{i=1,\ldots,n}\left|p(\lambda_i)\right|
\leq\min_{p\in\Pi_k}\max_{\lambda\in[\lambda_1,\lambda_n]}\left|p(\lambda)\right|
$$
and using Chebyshev polynomials (with some scaling and shifting) to bound the maximum.

If the spectrum has a few large outliers, say, $\lambda_1\leq\cdots\leq\lambda_m\ll\lambda_{m+1}\leq\cdots\leq\lambda_n$ (somewhat generalizing your assumptions), the idea is quite simple. In the first min-max problem, take (as a "candidate" to get rid of the minimum) a polynomial of the form
$$
p(\lambda)=q_{n-m}(\lambda)\tilde{p}(\lambda),
$$
where $q_{n-m}\in\Pi_{n-m}$ and $\tilde{p}\in\Pi_{k-n+m}$ (for $k=n-m,n-m+1,\ldots$) and such that $q_{n-m}$ is zero for $\lambda=\lambda_i$, $i=m+1,\ldots,n$. Such a polynomial is simple:
$$
q_{n-m}(\lambda)=\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{\lambda_{m+1}}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{\lambda_n}\right).
$$
The effect of this choice is that the maximum then does not depend on the values of $p$ at these points (since the polynomial attains zero there):
$$
\min_{p\in\Pi_k}\max_{i=1,\ldots,n}\left|p(\lambda_i)\right|
\leq
\min_{\tilde{p}\in\Pi_{k-n+m}}\max_{i=1,\ldots,m}\left|\tilde{p}(\lambda_i)\right|.
$$
Now, on the rest, use the same machinery as for the "classical" bound:
$$
\min_{\tilde{p}\in\Pi_{k-n+m}}\max_{i=1,\ldots,m}\left|\tilde{p}(\lambda_i)\right|\leq\min_{\tilde{p}\in\Pi_{k-n+m}}\max_{\lambda\in[\lambda_1,\lambda_m]}\left|\tilde{p}(\lambda)\right|
\leq 2\left(\frac{\sqrt{\kappa_m}-1}{\sqrt{\kappa_m}+1}\right)^{k-n+m},
$$
where $\kappa_m:=\lambda_m/\lambda_1$ is by assumption much smaller than $\kappa$. Note that this bound is "active" for $k=n-m,n-m+1,\ldots$ (to make the candidate polynomial annihilate all outliers) and that you should be aware of [rounding errors](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s11075-013-9713-z).